# CoreML custom layer: Pixelwise Normalization with Metal Shaders

Tags: c++, tensorflow, keras, metal, coreml

I'm converting Nvidia's Progressive Growing of GANs' Generator to coreML. I've managed to get everything transferred to coreML with the exception of the Pixelwise Normalization (Lambda) layer, which I plan on implementing as a custom coreML layer in Swift/Metal.

In TensorFlow.Keras, I have implemented pixel norm as

```
def pixelwise_norm(a):
    return a / tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(a * a, axis=3, keep_dims=True) + 1e-8)
```

Now, I've barely ever worked with shaders/Metal, but Following the instructions here: http://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-custom-layers/, I have a custom layer set up to use Metal for feedforward operations. I am using a MTLComputePipelineState that (calls? encodes?) the following shader for the layer's operations:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;


kernel void pixelwise_norm(
              texture2d_array<half, access::read> inTexture [[texture(0)]],
              texture2d_array<half, access::write> outTexture [[texture(1)]],
              ushort3 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    if (gid.x >= outTexture.get_width() ||
        gid.y >= outTexture.get_height()) {
        return;
    }

    const float4 x = float4(inTexture.read(gid.xy, gid.z));
    const float4 y = 0.0000001f + (x / sqrt(pow(x,2)));
    outTexture.write(half4(y), gid.xy, gid.z);
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the metal equivalent of "reduce_mean", right now this shader implements a ~tensorflow ~operation like

```
return a / tf.sqrt((a * a) + 1e-8)
```

Does anyone have any pointers?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, for every pixel in the feature map this divides that pixel by the L2 norm over that pixel's channels?

In that case you'll need to use a for loop to read the channels for that pixel, sum up these numbers, and divide by the number of channels. (You only need to do this loop if the number of channels is more than 4.)

Also note that your 1e-8 needs to be inside the sqrt() or at least in the denominator.

Comment: Yeah that's the idea, there are going to be anywhere from 3 to 512 channels depending on the layer's location in the network. As it is written now, x refers to (a single pixel/location in xy, and the channels z for the given xy), correct? or does it refer to specific xy planes indexed by z? Sorry for the basic questions, this is pretty far outside of my usual field of work

Comment: In the code you've provided, `x` contains 4 channels worth of data since you're reading from a single texture slice (in particular, the slice at `gid.z`) which gives you a `float4`. So instead of dividing the pixel by the norm over all the channels, you're dividing each pixel by the norm over just the 4 channels that are in this texture slice.

Comment: Gotcha, and because of how metal works I can't get x as all 512 channels (at least with the gid.xyzwabc... format). Instead I have to do a loop over the inTexture?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Because pixel x will have 512 channels, you need to read the value for that pixel from all 512 / 4 = 128 texture slices, square them and sum these up.